# How to get all substrings matching a regex pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am using RegEx in Python and I'm having some trouble to find all the substrings matching a given pattern. For example:

```
import re 
pattern = '\d{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$' 
text = 'I want to match this two: 01234567A and this 89012345B'
```

When I apply the RegEx, I would expect to obtain both `89012345B` and `01234567A`, but I am only getting the last value (`89012345B`). What I've tried so far is:

```
match = re.search(pattern, text)
print(match.group())
>>> '89012345B'

match = re.finditer(pattern, text)
print([match.group() for match in matches])
>>> ['89012345B']

match = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(match)
>>> ['89012345B']
```

As you can see, this only returns the last match. What am I missing? How could I get both?

Comment: `pattern = r'\b\d{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]\b'`. `$` matches the end of string, you need a word boundary to match a whole *word*.

Comment: Your issue is that `$` in your pattern meant that it could only match at the end of the string.